# How to replace spring's xml file during build process

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, build, maven-war-plugin

I am bundling my spring mvc web application into a single war file currently, and the problem is my development version of my spring context xml file is being deployed to my server.

I have allot of debug or non-optimized configurations for mysql and hibernate in my xml file.

How can I swap this file with a production version during the build process?

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows you to use various config xml files based on your build environment.  Here's a tutorial on how to do it:

http://hmkcode.com/spring-profile-xml-configuration/

In addition, maven allows you to run separate builds for different environments:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html